# SelectMany in Linq and dimensional array?

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, linq, .net-4.0

Why this code compiles :

```
byte[][] my2DArray =new  byte  [][]{  
                        new byte[] {1, 2},
                        new byte[] {3, 4},
                       };
 
  var r = my2DArray.SelectMany(f=> f);
```

while this one isn't :

```
byte[,] my2DArray =new byte [2,2]{  
                                   {1, 2},
                                   {3, 4},
                                 };
 
   var r = my2DArray.SelectMany(f=> f);
```

isn't `[][]` is as `[,]` ?

## edit

why do I need that ?

I need to create a single dimension array  so it will be sent to  `GetArraySum`

of course I can create overload , but I wanted to transform the mutli dim into one dim. (`GetArraySum` serves also   pure dimensional arrays).

```
void Main()
{
    byte[][] my2DArray =new  byte  [][]{  
                                         new byte[] {1, 2},
                                         new byte[] {3, 4},
                                      };
 
      var sum = GetArraySum(my2DArray.SelectMany(f=> f).ToArray());
      
}



 int GetArraySum(byte [] ar)
 {
 return ar.Select(r=>(int)r).Sum();
 }
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> isn't [][] is as [,]

No. A `byte[][]` is a [*jagged array*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2s05feca.aspx) - an array of arrays. Each element of the "outer" array is a reference to a normal `byte[]` (or a null reference, of course).

A `byte[,]` is a [*rectangular array*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s7e8s029.aspx) - a single object.

Rectangular arrays don't implement `IEnumerable<T>`, only the non-generic `IEnumerable`, but you could use `Cast` to cast each item to a `byte`:

```
byte[,] rectangular = ...;
var doubled = rectangular.Cast<byte>().Select(x => (byte) x * 2);
```

That will just treat the rectangular array as a single sequence of bytes though - it *isn't* a sequence of "subarrays" in the same way as you would with a jagged array though... you couldn't use `Cast<byte[]>` for example.

Personally I rarely use multidimensional arrays of either kind - what are you trying to achieve here? There may be a better approach.

EDIT: If you're just trying to sum everything in a rectangular array, it's easy:

```
int sum = array.Cast<byte>().Sum(x => (int) x);
```

After all, you don't really care about how things are laid out - you just want the sum of all the values (assuming I've interpreted your question correctly).

Comment: and since it's a single object , he can't find another inside Ienumerables ...right ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir: Not quite - the problem is that it only implements `IEnumerable`, not `IEnumerable<T>`, and definitely not `IEnumerable<byte[]>`.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know `[,]` is a _single_ object , that was my problem....Again, Thank you.

Comment: Good answer. It's a little unfortunate that an array `T[,]` (or `T[,,]` and so on) is not an `IEnumerable<T>` even if it's okay to `foreach` through it. I would also use `rectangular.Cast<byte>()` but it boxes and unboxes all elements and is not pretty. When .NET 2.0 was made they decided to magically have a uni-dimensional `T[]` array be assignable to the new generic `IList<T>` interface, but they didn't care to make a `T[,]` array implement any generic interfaces.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen: Rectangular arrays are basically annoying on various levels... as are arrays with non-zero lower bounds.

Comment: @JonSkeet why did you had to `Cast` in `array.Cast<byte>().Sum(x => (int) x);` ? each element _is_ byte...

Comment: @RoyiNamir: Because `Sum` only works over an `IEnumerable<T>`, and the rectangular array only implements the non-generic `IEnumerable` interface.

Comment: _"Rectangular arrays are basically annoying on various levels"_ I also never use them. But they help me answer some questions on Stack Overflow. Maybe one could use an extension method: `public static IEnumerable<T> AsEnumerable<T>(this T[,] arr) { foreach (var t in arr) yield return t; }` because `array.AsEnumerable().WhateverLinqMethod()` looks better than `array.Cast<RepeatElementTypeHere>().WhateverLinqMethod()`.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen: Well if you're going to have an extension method targeting them specifically, you could avoid the boxing by fetching the lengths and using a nested `for` loop. If you want to keep the current behaviour, just use `Cast<T>` within the method - simpler than rewriting it yourself :)

Comment: @JonSkeet Interesting. Does boxing occur in the following code: `byte[] arr = XXX; foreach (var t in arr) { /* something */ }`. Does it matter if `arr` is one-dimensional or multi-dimensional, or does boxing always occur when you `foreach` through an array whose element type is a value type?

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen: No, it wouldn't in that case. And actually, you could be right in the `[,]` case as well... just checking now... yup, the compiler generates code calling `GetLowerBound`, `GetUpperBound` etc. Ignore me - too sleepy :)

Comment: @JonSkeet didn't you mean `Rectangular arrays don't implement ` instead of `Jagged arrays don't implement` ? cause your sample is with Rectangular.

Comment: @JonSkeet - When modeling a chessboard, for example, would you use a jagged array or a rectangular array? I thought to use a rectangular array since it is really a rectangular "being" and not an array of arrays, but your answer made me wonder...

Comment: @Sipo: Probably rectangular, but it would be encapsulated in a `Board` class anyway, so I could give that whatever functionality I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

This wont compile, because `[,]` is multidimensional array and `[][]` is array-of-arrays ([msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288453%28v=vs.71%29.aspx))

So, your first example will return arrays, where as second - it is complicated