# How do I find the min and max value of a multidimensional array?

Tags: vb.net, multidimensional-array

I want to find the minimum and maximum values of this array. At some point it is set to `(512, 512)` UShorts. A For loop would be very time consuming for this many points and am looking for something cleaner. SelectMany occurred to me but I don't know how to implement it.

```vb
Dim usResult As UShort(,)
```

edit:
I have tried

```vb
Dim minValue As UShort = UShort.MaxValue
Dim maxValue As UShort = UShort.MinValue
Dim sw As New Stopwatch()
sw.Start()
For i As Integer = 0 To 511 Step 1
    For j As Integer = 0 To 511 Step 1
        minValue = Math.Min(usResult(i, j), minValue)
        maxValue = Math.Max(usResult(i, j), maxValue)
    Next
Next
sw.Stop()
Console.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds)
' This takes 2 to 3 milliseconds
```

Comment: Unless you use a specialized data structure which keeps data sorted or keeps track of the smallest/greatest elements, you *have* to loop through all elements of the array.

Comment: I will need to compute this min and max as quickly as possible (tracking laser beam movements, want as low as possible time resolution). The for loop seems to be the quickest solution since the data won't be sorted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A for loop might be much less time-consuming than you expect. Try timing it to see how long it takes to find the min and max 100,000 times with nested loops.

Comment: Although it's not as fast as I'd like, the for loop seems the be my best solution in terms of performance. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way to get min/max of a multi-dimensional array is by doing this:

```
Dim max As UShort = usResult.Cast(Of UShort).Max()
Dim min As UShort = usResult.Cast(Of UShort).Min()
```

It doesn't offer better performance than a for loop though. You would need to use a specialized data structure that keeps elements sorted, or keeps track of min/max elements, to get better performance.

Comment: Very clean implementation. I'm trying to understand how it flattens the array. Why the cast to UShort - Isn't it already UShort?

Comment: Good questions, look at Jon Skeet's answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14030140/selectmany-in-linq-and-dimensional-array . The multi-dimensional array implements IEnumerable, which enumerates all values (flattened). But for some reason it doesn't implement the generic version, `IEnumerable<T>`, so it's enumerating values cast as type `Object`. That's why you have to cast to the concrete type, `UShort`.

Comment: I noticed the tooltip of the Cast() function said `Casts the elements of an *System.Collections.IEnumerable* to the specified type.` ... `As *System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable(Of TResult)*`, the generic you mentioned. Jon Skeet cleared it up nicely. Thanks again