# Append Multiple Arrays Together using VB.Net

Tags: arrays, .net, vb.net

I have a jagged array that contains 40 different arrays. Each one of them has dimensions (250, 250, 2).

I'd like to combine them all into a new array with dimensions (250 * 40, 250 * 40, 2 * 40).

Starting with the first array `lbound(jagged)` to the last `ubound(jagged)`.

What is a good approach to doing this? I was thinking of simply using loop:

```
Dim DWG(250 * 40, 250 * 40, 2 * 40) as Double
Dim jagged(40)() as Double = GetArrays(jagged) ' get 40 arrays    
Dim arr(250, 250, 2) as Double

for i = 0 to ubound(jagged)        
    arr = jagged(i)
    for channel = 0 to ubound(arr, 3) 
        for row = 0 to ubound(arr, 1) 
            for column = 0 to ubound(arr, 2) 
                DWG(row + (250 * i), column + ( 250 * i), channel + (2 * i)) = arr(row, column, channel)
            next
        next
    next
next
```

I can confirm the above code works. Still seems like there could be a better approach. Just for a little context I'm editing pixel data.

Comment: Well does it work? If so there is probably no better way. Anything that looks more elegant, like LINQ for example, will use for loops behind the scenes anyway and will be less efficient.

Comment: @djv, yes the above code works. I tested it. I'll leave the question open for a bit longer I guess to see if there are other recommendations. Otherwise maybe I'll just answer it myself. Thanks.

Comment: stack overflow is for broken code. [codereview.se] might help with improving it

Comment: @junfanbl it reminds me of [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14631599/832052) I asked a while back, at a time when I was learning about LINQ and wanted to use it for everything, but I learned using loops is OK

Comment: @djv, this is a good point you make, thank you. Should I just close the question then, or is it helpful to leave it up?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @junfanbl the community might close it anyway. Not bad for this question to exist (albeit closed) for posterity